# Replace a part of a string

Tags: c++

Annotation:
In my code I have edited the string at an adneren position, this I have not had in my example.
Since here the actual error cause/problem lay I have adapted the example, see example below.

The Answer should be:
std::string.resize increases the memory size of the string to the maximum expected size.
replace inserts the entire size into str0.

A solution is to execute resize only if str1.lengh > max_len.

**Original question:**

I would like to insert a string (str1) into another (str0), at any position (n).
If str1 is shorter than the rest of string str0 (n -> str0.end()), the rest of str0 should remain.

For this I wanted to use the std::string::replace() function.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::string str0 = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    std::string str1 = "000";
    
    uint16_t n = 3;

    str0.replace(n, str1.length(), str1);

    std::cout << "TEST:" << str0 << std::endl;


    return 0;
 
}
```

In my example, I expect to output "TEST: ABC000GHIJ" via cout.

However, "TEST: ABC000" is output.
Where is the problem that the string will be cutted?

Correct code example with the error cause:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <iostream>

#define max_len 20

int main()
{

    std::string str0 = "ABDCDEF";
    std::string str1 = "";
    
    uint16_t n = 3;

    std::getline(std::cin, str1);

    if(!str1.empty() && str1[str1.size()-1] == '\n') {
        str1.erase(str1.size()-1);
    }
    str1.resize(max_len);

    str0.replace(n, str1.length(), str1);

    std::cout << "TEST:" << str0 << std::endl;


    return 0;
 
}
```

Comment: Your code produces `TEST:ABC000GHIJ` for me. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Did you recompile the code after your last edit, and are you executing the correct executable?

Comment: So i work on a qnx 6.6 arm system with gcc 4.7.3 compiler. 
In my test case i use the std::cin. I already checked for '\n' || '\r' and delete it. 

I will adjust my example in a few minutes

Comment: std:string has an insert() member function if you'd rather use that.

Comment: With your edit, the question becomes unclear with regards to observed behavior, expected behavior. Also, your handling of newlines is wrong -- because `std::getline` does not place the newline into the string read, and if it did, `str1.empty()` would be false (as `empty()` does **not** ignore whitespaces). Your program overwrites `str0`, starting after the fourth character, with what the user entered. *What did you expect?*

Comment: So just to clarify: do you mean that the first code example does NOT reproduce the problem? If so, please remove that example completely since it is only misleading then. I think it's better to make ONE clear, valid question then to keep all history in the question text. We can already view all old revisions, so there's no reason to keep outdated or confusing information in the question. Also, the answer should NOT be part of the question body, but should be posted as an answer instead.

Comment: Your "correct code example" is full of randomly inserted code fragments that have no apparent purpose. To achieve the declared goal, you need the first example exactly as is, nothing more, nothing less. Why do you need any of the code in the second example?